# OpenShift upgrade error 4.11.x -> 4.12.2 Marking Degraded due to: unexpected on-disk state validating against rendered-worker

Tags: openshift

I'm administrating RHEL OpenShift cluster.  I'm upgrading from 4.10.x -> 4.11.x -> 4.12.2
There are 3 masters, and 7 worker nodes.

all 3 masters updated
3 of the 8 workers updated.

Thus far the upgrade is now stuck on worker0 with:

```
oc logs machine-config-daemon-4bs9x -n openshift-machine-config-operator
< snip >
I0216 21:00:08.555947    3136 daemon.go:1255] Current config: rendered-worker-8ebd95b2c00a22992daf1248ebc5640f
I0216 21:00:08.555986    3136 daemon.go:1256] Desired config: rendered-worker-263c6ea5fafb6f1da35a31749a1180d7
I0216 21:00:08.555992    3136 daemon.go:1258] state: Degraded
I0216 21:00:08.566365    3136 update.go:2089] Running: rpm-ostree cleanup -r
Deployments unchanged.
I0216 21:00:08.647332    3136 update.go:2104] Disk currentConfig rendered-worker-263c6ea5fafb6f1da35a31749a1180d7 overrides node's currentConfig annotation rendered-worker-8ebd95b2c00a22992daf1248ebc5640f
I0216 21:00:08.651201    3136 daemon.go:1564] Validating against pending config rendered-worker-263c6ea5fafb6f1da35a31749a1180d7
E0216 21:00:10.291740    3136 writer.go:200] Marking Degraded due to: unexpected on-disk state validating against rendered-worker-263c6ea5fafb6f1da35a31749a1180d7: expected target osImageURL "quay.io/openshift-release-dev/ocp-v4.0-art-dev@sha256:f454144d2c32aa6fd99b8c68082f59554751282865dce6a866916d3c75fb02ee", have "quay.io/openshift-release-dev/ocp-v4.0-art-dev@sha256:73b311468554ffe8bdd0dd51df7dafd7a791a16c3147374cc7b28f0d3d7fcc17" ("b5390d80a8b7f90b0b64f9db3e92848591c967612740716c656c6e88696e0c3f")
```

I've had this problem before and followed the RedHat solutions to run the following command.  But this is now failing.

```
oc debug node/worker0.xx.com
sh-4.4# chroot /host

sh-4.4# rpm-ostree status
State: idle
Deployments:
* db83d20cf09a263777fcca78594b16da00af8acc245d29cc2a1344abc3f0dac2
                  Version: 412.86.202301311551-0 (2023-01-31T15:54:05Z)
sh-4.4# 

sh-4.4#  /run/bin/machine-config-daemon pivot   "quay.io/openshift-release-dev/ocp-v4.0-art-dev@sha256:f454144d2c32aa6fd99b8c68082f59554751282865dce6a8669163c75fb02ee"
I0216 21:02:54.449270 3962714 run.go:19] Running: nice -- ionice -c 3 oc image extract --path /:/run/mco-machine-os-content/os-content-821872843 --registry-config /var/lib/kubelet/config.json quay.io/openshift-release-dev/ocp-v4.0-art-dev@sha256:f454144d2c32aa6fd99b8c68082f59554751282865dce6a866916d3c75fb02ee
I0216 21:03:48.349962 3962714 rpm-ostree.go:209] Previous pivot: quay.io/openshift-release-dev/ocp-v4.0-art-dev@sha256:73b311468554ffe8bdd0dd51df7dafd7a791a16c3147374cc7b28f0d3d7fcc17
I0216 21:03:49.926169 3962714 rpm-ostree.go:246] No com.coreos.ostree-commit label found in metadata! Inspecting...
I0216 21:03:49.926234 3962714 rpm-ostree.go:412] Running captured: ostree refs --repo /run/mco-machine-os-content/os-content-821872843/srv/repo
error: error running ostree refs --repo /run/mco-machine-os-content/os-content-821872843/srv/repo: exit status 1
error: opening repo: opendir(/run/mco-machine-os-content/os-content-821872843/srv/repo): No such file or directory

sh-4.4#
```

After a reboot and retry now I'm getting:

```
sh-4.4# /run/bin/machine-config-daemon pivot   "quay.io/openshift-release-dev/ocp-v4.0-art-dev@sha256:f454144d2c32aa6fd99b8c68082f59554751282865dce6a866916375fb02ee"
I0217 19:10:06.928154 1443914 run.go:19] Running: nice -- ionice -c 3 oc image extract --path /:/run/mco-machine-os-content/os-content-903744214 --registry-config /var/lib/kubelet/config.json quay.io/openshift-release-dev/ocp-v4.0-art-dev@sha256:f454144d2c32aa6fd99b8c68082f59554751282865dce6a8669163c75fb02ee
error: "quay.io/openshift-release-dev/ocp-v4.0-art-dev@sha256:f454144d2c32aa6fd99b8c68082f59554751282865dce6a8669163c75fb02ee" is not a valid image reference: invalid checksum digest length
W0217 19:10:07.176459 1443914 run.go:45] nice failed: running nice -- ionice -c 3 oc image extract --path /:/run/mco-machine-os-content/os-content-903744214 --registry-config /var/lib/kubelet/config.json quay.io/openshift-release-dev/ocp-v4.0-art-dev@sha256:f454144d2c32aa6fd99b8c68082f59554751282865dce6a8669163c75fb02ee failed: error: "quay.io/openshift-release-dev/ocp-v4.0-art-dev@sha256:f454144d2c32aa6fd99b8c68082f59554751282865dce6a8669163c75fb02ee" is not a valid image reference: invalid checksum digest length
: exit status 1; retrying...
^C
```

I tried this:

```
/run/bin/machine-config-daemon pivot   "quay.io/openshift-release-dev/ocp-v4.0-art-dev@sha256:f454144d2c32aa6fd99b8c68082f59554751282865dce6a866916375fb02ee"
```

expecting this result ( from a previous upgrade problem ):

```
sh-4.4# chroot /host
sh-4.4# /run/bin/machine-config-daemon pivot "quay.io/openshift-release-dev/ocp-v4.0-art-dev@sha256:73b311468554ffe8bdd0dd51df7dafd7a791a16c3147374cc7b28f0d3d7fcc17"
I0208 21:50:00.408235 2962835 run.go:19] Running: nice -- ionice -c 3 oc image extract --path /:/run/mco-machine-os-content/os-content-3432684387 --registry-config /var/lib/kubelet/config.json quay.io/openshift-release-dev/ocp-v4.0-art-dev@sha256:73b311468554ffe8bdd0dd51df7dafd7a791a16c3147374cc7b28f0d3d7fcc17
I0208 21:50:29.727695 2962835 rpm-ostree.go:353] Running captured: rpm-ostree status --json
I0208 21:50:29.780350 2962835 rpm-ostree.go:261] Previous pivot: quay.io/openshift-release-dev/ocp-v4.0-art-dev@sha256:7c252d64354d207cd7fb2a6e2404e611a29bf214f63a97345dee1846055c15d8
I0208 21:50:31.456928 2962835 rpm-ostree.go:293] Pivoting to: 411.86.202301242231-0 (b5390d80a8b7f90b0b64f9db3e92848591c967612740716c656c6e88696e0c3f)
I0208 21:50:31.456966 2962835 rpm-ostree.go:325] Executing rebase from repo path /run/mco-machine-os-content/os-content-3432684387/srv/repo with customImageURL pivot://quay.io/openshift-release-dev/ocp-v4.0-art-dev@sha256:73b311468554ffe8bdd0dd51df7dafd7a791a16c3147374cc7b28f0d3d7fcc17 and checksum b5390d80a8b7f90b0b64f9db3e92848591c967612740716c656c6e88696e0c3f
I0208 21:50:31.457048 2962835 update.go:1972] Running: rpm-ostree rebase --experimental /run/mco-machine-os-content/os-content-3432684387/srv/repo:b5390d80a8b7f90b0b64f9db3e92848591c967612740716c656c6e88696e0c3f --custom-origin-url pivot://quay.io/openshift-release-dev/ocp-v4.0-art-dev@sha256:73b311468554ffe8bdd0dd51df7dafd7a791a16c3147374cc7b28f0d3d7fcc17 --custom-origin-description Managed by machine-config-operator
0 metadata, 0 content objects imported; 0 bytes content written
Staging deployment... done
Upgraded:
  NetworkManager 1:1.30.0-16.el8_4 -> 1:1.36.0-12.el8_6
< snip>
  zlib 1.2.11-18.el8_4 -> 1.2.11-19.el8_6
Removed:
  ModemManager-glib-1.10.8-2.el8.x86_64
  libmbim-1.20.2-1.el8.x86_64
  libqmi-1.24.0-1.el8.x86_64
  openvswitch2.16-2.16.0-108.el8fdp.x86_64
  redhat-release-coreos-410.84-2.el8.x86_64
Added:
  WALinuxAgent-udev-2.3.0.2-2.el8_6.3.noarch
  glibc-gconv-extra-2.28-189.5.el8_6.x86_64
  libbpf-0.4.0-3.el8.x86_64
  openvswitch2.17-2.17.0-67.el8fdp.x86_64
  redhat-release-8.6-0.1.el8.x86_64
  redhat-release-eula-8.6-0.1.el8.x86_64
  shadow-utils-subid-2:4.6-16.el8.x86_64
Run "systemctl reboot" to start a reboot
sh-4.4# systemctl reboot
```

Comment: After you changed the image with `pivot` command, what is the error in `machine-config-daemon`?

Comment: aftrer the pivot command, I get the same error in the machine-config-daemon pod's logs:
```
E0220 15:21:37.425285 3330 writer.go:200] Marking Degraded due to: unexpected on-disk state validating against rendered-worker-263c6ea5fafb6f1da35a31749a1180d7: expected target osImageURL "quay.io/openshift-release-dev/ocp-v4.0-art-dev@sha256:f454144d2c32aa6fd99b8c68082f59554751282865dce6a866916d3c75fb02ee", have "quay.io/openshift-release-dev/ocp-v4.0-art-dev@sha256:73b311468554ffe8bdd0dd51df7dafd7a791a16c3147374cc7b28f0d3d7fcc17" 
```

Comment: In such case one might take advantage from Red Hat KB Solution 5598401 [Cluster Updates Without Error but Machine Config Pools Degraded with `Marking Degraded due to: unexpected on-disk state` on OCP 4.6 and newer](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/5598401) ...